# image.onload in function - why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I'm new using JS. I want to keep all of the information about an object in one place.
So I've made this function:

```
function Obiekt(img) {
this.img = img;
this.ready = false;
this.image = new Image();
this.image.src = this.img;
this.image.onload = function() {
    ready = true;
};
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;
this.rotation = 0;
}
```

Then I've made my object, named hero.

```
var hero = new Obiekt("images/hero.png");
```

Problem is, hero.ready is always false and I can't draw this.

```
if (hero.ready) {
     ctx.drawImage(hero.image, 0, 0);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: the `ready` variable you use on your `onload` does not refer to the same `this.ready` that is found before. You'll have to use another kind of reference (f.i. use `var that=this` outside the `onload` and `that.ready` inside). Also, your `onload` should probably be defined before the `src`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems :

- `ready` can't be found
- If your image is cached (depending on the browser), the order you used can't work as the image isn't loaded after you set the callback.

Here's a solution :

```
var _this = this;
this.image.onload = function() {
    _this.ready = true;
};
this.image.src = this.img;
```

(and I'd add that the naming isn't very good : I'd prefer `imgsrc` over `img`)